# Run a bash script without asking to display contents

Tags: bash

I'm writing a couple-lines file of bash scripts that launches a Mono application, but when I double click the file, it asks whether I want to run, run in terminal, or display contents--how do I set the file to run automatically, without this pop-up? I'm trying to reduce as many steps as I can for an end-user.

The pop-up in question's specifics:

- Title text: "Do you want to run (filename, no extension), or display its contents?"
- Subtext: "(filename,no ext) is an executable text file."
- Options: Run in Terminal, Display, Cancel, Run
  (Except display also runs it...)

System: Mint 19

Comment: Batch file? that sounds like a windows thing. Do you mean Bash script?

Comment: new to Linux--I believe that's what I mean, yeah. I have a text file with bash scripts in it.

Comment: I wouldn't double-click an icon. I would open Terminal, cd to the directory and enter `bash ./script.sh` to execute it.

Comment: ultimately, this is for an end-user who won't do anything but start the app off the desktop, and probs won't know anything about Linux--thus the shortcut.

Comment: Your question is off-topic here, please ask over on [unix.se] instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a launcher. Open a text file and paste:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=foo
Exec=/path/to/your/script
Icon=
Type=Application
```

Now double click on it, it should do the trick. Maybe a pop-up will show, to mark as a trusted app, but just once.

Comment: what does the .desktop extension do for the system?

Comment: the launcher did it! Seems strange to have a launcher file to a script file to a mono app, but if it gets rid of the pop-up, all is well in the world.

Comment: Glad it works. For the desktop extension, I was wrong I think, I will edit the answer accordingly. Right now I'm on mint cinnamon.

Comment: this is the better comment, ignore mine.

Comment: It doesn't work for 20.2 version of Linux Mint

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file is called something like *launch.sh*:

1. Make sure your file has a proper [shebang](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Shebang)
2. Rename the file to remove the extension .sh. `mv launch.sh launch`
3. Make *launch* executable. `chmod +x launch`

This should just run without the warning popup.

Comment: shebang line--check. extension removed--probably? I started with a .txt file, and I don't see an extension in properties. executibility--I did run that line, don't know how to find proof. but the pop-up continues. I'll include more info about the pop-up in the post.

Comment: to find proof go into your terminal and run `ls SCRIPTNAME` it should not have a .sh or .txt at the end.